# When coming out of suspend, syslog keeps spamming i2c_hid i2c-DELL0817:00: i2c_hid_get_input

Tags: 16.04, kernel, suspend, power-management

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 with i3wm as window manager. I am working on a Dell Latitude with an external monitor. The laptop lid is closed.

When coming out of suspension (which I trigger via `pm-suspend`), I see a high usage of systemd-journal in `top`. In addition, the following line is repeated in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kernel.log` at a very high rate:

```
katrinetw-Latitude-5590 kernel: [ 8156.991270] i2c_hid i2c-DELL0817:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (30/2)
```

I can only fix this by rebooting the laptop. How can I analyze and fix this properly?

Is there a way to reset or reload certain things so I might get out of this loop?

```
katrinetw@katrinetw-Latitude-5590:/var/log$ uname -r
4.15.0-43-generic
```

I'll leave my laptop running, so I am happy and available to provide further information.

**Update**

I found some information on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784152.

In my case, the spamming seems to stop when I open the lid and use the touchpad for a second. I am very interested to find a way to resolve this without this manual intervention.